# Multiple instances of the same button in tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid

I am quite new to coding, but I have googled this extensively and found nothing. It is quite possible I am missing something obvious, so please bear with me. I am trying to code a simple tkinter window that puts up multiple instances of the same button, but when I run the code it only puts the button up once. I could make several buttons and grid them separately, but that doesn't scale well if you want to increase the number of buttons. Here's what I have:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Button Grid")

def place_button(x, y):
    button1.grid(row = y, column = x)

button1 = Button(root, text = "O", padx = 10, pady = 10, command = press)

plane = [
(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0),
(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1),
(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)
]

for i in plane:
    place_button(*i)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this help you...

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Button Grid")
root.geometry("500x700+100+50")

def place_button(x, y):
    button1 = Button(root, text = "O", padx = 10, pady = 10, command = '')
    button1.grid(row = y, column = x)

plane = [
(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0),
(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1),
(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)
]

for i,j in plane:
    place_button(i,j)
root.mainloop()
```